# How to do sensor fusion?

Tags: sensors, robotics

Let suppose that I have two measures from two difference sensors of the same variable. I'd like to know if there's a way to do an information fusion and obtain a unique measure that describes the best way possible the whole system (Both sensors).

I know Bar-Shalom - Campo sensor fusion model, but I'd like to know if there are any model that doesn't adopte the classical Gaussian assumption, so that the sensor fusion can deal with bad data/gross erros.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, as you did this twice. Plural form of `sensor` is `sensors` not `sensores`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thank you so much for the useful information. 
Sensores is a portuguese word that means sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sensor fusion, you can go for Kalman Filter. There are few tutorials and research papers available for extended kalman filter, used for sensor fusion.

Answer (score 0):

It extremely depends on which sensor types you are trying to fuse. Some sensors noises can not be modeled using Gaussian RV. Even if the sensor noises are not well fit with Gaussian RV, Kalman filter and Gaussian assumption works well in most cases. You might inspect the GPS position estimate example. You could fuse the data of multiple satellites using nonlinear Kalman filter(UKF etc.) or least-squares.